# Query Building with Knex/Postgres (nested Json)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to build a query that will change all 'assets' status to 'Pending Transfer' where location equals the location in the request's body data.

An entry on the "location" column in my "assets" table is as follows:

```
{"site":"Xxxxx, XX","site_loc":{"shelf":"89","unit":"89"}}
```

This is the knex query I'm trying to build:

```
async function bulkUpdate(req, res){
  const site = req.body.data;
  const data = await knex('assets')
  .whereRaw(`location -> 'site' = '${site.physical_site_name}'`)
  .update("status", "Pending Transfer") //todo: update history as well
  .returning('*')
  .then((results) => results[0]);
  res.status(200).json({ data });
}
```

There error I'm getting is:

```
message: `update "assets" set "status" = $1 where location -> 'site' = 'Xxxxx, XX' returning * - operator does not exist: json = unknown`
```

I've also tried using:

```
async function bulkUpdate(req, res){
  const site = req.body.data;
  const data = await knex('assets')
  // .whereRaw(`location -> 'site' = '${site.physical_site_name}'`)
  .whereJsonPath('location', '$.site', '=', `${site.physical_site_name}`)
  .update("status", "Pending Transfer") //todo: update history as well
  .returning('*')
  .then((results) => results[0]);
  res.status(200).json({ data });
}
```

Where I get the error:

```
message: `update "assets" set "status" = $1 where jsonb_path_query_first("location", $2) #>> '{}' = $3 returning * - function jsonb_path_query_first(json, unknown) does not exist`
```

I can't tell if this is because I'm using the '->' operator incorrectly, or if there is a different comparison I should use other than '='. Should I not be using the apostrophe's around site?

I'm fairly new at this, but I've been trying to research this and have been trying various ways and have yet to figure it out.

Any help on understanding this better would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh...

And the answer is:

```
.whereRaw(`location ->> 'site' = '${site.physical_site_name}'`)
```